# Docker image build failed with error code 128

Tags: docker

I created a dockerfile which generates the docker image with my node application. My application depends on my another application which is added as dependency using git ssh.

When docker build runs npm install, it fails with error code 128. I understand it is because i do not have valid ssh token to access repo. How can i create one and have my docker build pass?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate your local machine's key (do not provide any passcode for simplicity) that can be used for authentication. Now adding that key for git access depends on where your repository is i.e is it on hosted sites like bitbucket/github or just your another linux machine.

For repository on local server run below commands on your local machine to add your public key (id_rsa.pub) to git server.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add
ssh-copy-id user@git-server
```

For hosted sites you get the option to add the public-key under your profile settings.

Note: do not forget to add below in ~/.ssh/config file on your local machine to avoid the unknown host exception

```
Host bitbucket.org
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
Host <git-server-ip>
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

For more information on generating key please refer to https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html